# Android: the emulator process for AVD was killed

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtualbox

I run Android Studio in the Virtual box guest OS (Ubuntu 20.04.1). Guest OS has 4 processor cores and 8 GB RAM. KVM is enabled:

```
$ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
4
$ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists 
KVM acceleration can be used
```

Event log in Android studio is empty, in the console I see the following:
`Emulator terminated with exit code 139`. I found several posts with such code and set `Software` for `Emulate performance graphics` and `VM Heap size` to `512 MB` but with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution? For me, the following appeared in the Android Studio log:

```
2021-05-04 15:46:31,027 [79014767]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: /home/aj/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_3a_XL_API_30 
2021-05-04 15:46:31,248 [79014988]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf 
2021-05-04 15:46:31,336 [79015076]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: cannot add library /home/aj/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed 
2021-05-04 15:46:31,336 [79015076]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: added library /home/aj/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so 
2021-05-04 15:46:31,336 [79015076]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: cannot add library /home/aj/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1: full 
2021-05-04 15:46:31,394 [79015134]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INTEL-MESA: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0 
2021-05-04 15:46:31,394 [79015134]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator:  
2021-05-04 15:46:31,630 [79015370]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: emulator: INFO: EmulatorAdvertisement.cpp:93: Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_435941.ini 
2021-05-04 15:46:44,682 [79028422]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) 
2021-05-04 15:46:44,682 [79028422]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code 139
```

I will continue to investigate, I think a recent Ubuntu-update may have broken something.

EDIT: nevermind, I found the solution to my specific problem:
I was testing another project called tivi that depends on Android Studio Canary and started it in the emulator, must have updated the emulator to canary-version too (version 30.6.x).
Afterwards, I went back to my regular app-project in Android Studio stable and tried using any emulator image which always gave a generic error-message about "emulator process killed" and the log-messages above.

I deleted all my emulator images which didn't help.
But just now I tried reinstalling the android-emulator package from the SDK manager. Then it installed the correct version for AS-stable: 30.5.5.
With this version, the emulator works fine again.